# Android: Set Media-Player App as standart music player to catch external media inputs (NEXT SONG etc)

Tags: android

I am working on a media app, that playes mp3 on the phone. Simple as that.
However, I have a headset with a "start/stop" button on it. When I click this button, my phone automatically opens SAMSUNG MUSIC and plays a song that was currently on hold INSTEAD of stopping or playing the songs on my actively open app.
This is my broadcast receiver for the buttons:

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionMediaButton })]
    public class MyMediaButtonBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public string ComponentName { get { return Class.Name; } }

        Activity_Player xy = new Activity_Player();

        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            if (intent.Action != Intent.ActionMediaButton)
                return;

            var keyEvent = (KeyEvent)intent.GetParcelableExtra(Intent.ExtraKeyEvent);

            switch (keyEvent.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keycode.MediaPlay:
                    Toast.MakeText(Activity_Player.ctx, "XY", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    break;
                case Keycode.MediaPlayPause:
                    Toast.MakeText(Activity_Player.ctx, "XY", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    break;
                case Keycode.MediaNext:
                    xy.ChooseRandomNewSongAndPlay(false);
                    break;
                case Keycode.MediaPrevious:
                    Toast.MakeText(Activity_Player.ctx, "XY", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
```

So my question:

1.) Do I need to init this class in my main activity like so:

```
        receiver = new MyMediaButtonBroadcastReceiver();
```

2.) Do I need to set anything to my Manifest? Because there, the receiver is not registered.

3.) Do I need to set my own media player app as some sort of "standart" app anyway? (Maybe programatically, maybe somewhere in within the android os?), so that the pause and play buttons are mapped to MY app and not to the standart media player?

4.) You see, I have toast in my switch statement, just to see if anything is going to be triggered. So far, nothing is. Am I maybe missing something else?

Thank you for helping me out so often!

Answer (score 1):

So, to answer all my questions:

1) NO.
2) NO.
3) NO.
4:

```
    private void RegisterBroadCastReceiver()
    {
        var am = (AudioManager)this.GetSystemService(AudioService);
        var componentName = new ComponentName(PackageName, new MyMediaButtonBroadcastReceiver().ComponentName);
        am.RegisterMediaButtonEventReceiver(componentName);
    }
```

... do in OnCreate.

End of story!